# How do I access individual <span> for scraping web data in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm trying to scrape pricing data from a few home depot URLs. I'm using simple_html_dom.php which can be found here: https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/

I'm having issues figuring out how to get the individual span class that I need in order to get the data I want.

Here's an image of the inspect element with the various fields I'm trying to access:
https://prnt.sc/qx5ujt

Here's the code I have so far which returns an empty array:

```
?<php
require 'simple_html_dom.php';

$dom = file_get_html('https://www.homedepot.com/p/Zinsco-20-Amp-1-1-2-in-2-Pole-Replacement-Thick-Circuit-Breaker-UBIZ220/100183119', false);

$answer = array();
if(empty($dom))
{
     echo "EMPTY";
     exit;
} 
$divClass = "";
$dollars = "";
$cents = "";
$i = 0;
foreach($dom->find('price__wrapper') as $divClass) 
{
foreach($divClass->find('span[class=price__dollars]') as $dollars) //dollars
{
     $answer[$i]['dollars'] = $dollars->plaintext;
}
foreach($divClass->find('span[class=price__cents]') as $cents) //cents
{
     $answer[$i]['cents'] = $cents->plaintext;
}
$i++;
}

print_r($answer); 
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML really looks always like in the screenshot, than you can go on the `content` attribute of the parent span element.

This you can archive like below (untested example).

```php
// Get the parent span element with ID ajaxPrice
$element = $dom->find('span#ajaxPrice',0);
// Check if attribute "content" exists
if(isset($element->content)) {
    $price = $element->content; // This is the price as string value
    $priceFloat = floatval($price); // This is the price as float value

    // Splitting price in dollar and cent
    $price = explode('.', $price);
    $dollar = $price[0];
    $cent = $price[1];
}
```